# In a virtual env the sys.path is wrong when I import a package from a file

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyenv

The sys.path change only if I import a package from another file.

In my pyenv :

```
$(env) python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/var/www/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

In a fileImport.py (inside my virtual env) :

```
# fileImport.py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

the command :

```
$(env) python fileImport.py
```

gives me the same good result!

But when I try to import the fileImport package from anotherfile.py like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
# anotherfile.py    
import fileImport
```

the sys.path result change :

```
$(env) python anotherfile.py
['/var/www', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

I install pyenv like this :

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv python3-dev
$ pyvenv-3.4 env
```

I don't understand why the import from a file uses the sys.path from my system and not from my virtual env.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the shebang.

In a virtual env you can use :

```
$(env) /usr/bin/env python
```

but in a file the shebang must point to the exact location of your virtual python. In my case :

```
#!/var/www/bin/python
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Indeed, that was probably the cause. Just to note: since you don't set this script executable directly and try to execute it without `python`, you can completely remove *shebang*. It's not really needed when you specify directly to use python via `python` in command line, i.e. `python script.py`.

Comment: I'm agree but in my case the file is imported in a cgi script so I think that the shebang is the only way to specified the right python version. Thx